# PHP: how can I sort and filter an "array", that is an Object, implementing ArrayAccess?

Tags: php, arrays, spl, arrayaccess, countable

I have an object that is a collection of objects, behaving like an array. It's a database result object. Something like the following:

```
$users = User::get();
foreach ($users as $user)
    echo $user->name . "\n";
```

The `$users` variable is an object that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) and [`Countable`](http://php.net/Countable) interfaces.

I'd like to sort and filter this "array", but I can't use array functions on it:

```
$users = User::get();
$users = array_filter($users, function($user) {return $user->source == "Twitter";});
=> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

How *can I* sort and filter this kind of object?

Comment: it seems that user::get() function is not returning the array... check it out that it returns array

Comment: Your best option is probably to just implement a "toArray" method on your Users object.

Comment: ArrayAccess and Countable are not sufficient to iterate over all elements, you still need to know the keys. In my opinion, tweaking `User::get()` to accept additional information about the type of users requested is the way to go. Things like sorting and filtering are data-based tasks and therefore best done by the database.

Comment: If it's an SQL result set then why not get SQL to do the sorting for you?

Comment: @GordonM: because sometimes the filter and sort functions are a little too complicated for SQL and I don't want to litter my DB with procedures, that stuff belongs to the application logic, e.g. a DB model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. The purpose of the `ArrayAccess` interface is not just to create an OOP wrapper for arrays (although it is often used as such), but also to allow array-like access to collections that might not even know all their elements from the beginning. Imagine a web service client, that calls a remote procedure in `offsetGet()` and `offsetSet()`. You can access arbitrary elements, but you cannot access the whole collection - this is not part of the `ArrayAccess` interface.

If the object also implements `Traversable` (via [`Iterator`](http://php.net/iterator) or [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/iteratoraggregate)), an array could at least be constructed from it ([`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator-to-array) does the job). But you still have to convert it like that, the native array functions **only** accept arrays.

If your object stores the data internally as an array, the most efficient solution is of course to implement a `toArray()` method that returns this array (and maybe calls `toArray()` recursively on contained objects).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) instead of `ArrayAccess`, it has multiple native sort functionality:

- [`ArrayObject::asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.asort.php)
- [`ArrayObject::ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.ksort.php)
- [`ArrayObject::natcasesort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.natcasesort.php)
- [`ArrayObject::natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.natsort.php)
- [`ArrayObject::uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php)
- [`ArrayObject::uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uksort.php)