# Which SPL interface I must implement to be able to use usort() function on an object?

Tags: php, spl, usort

I have a class that represents a collection entity : it has only one attribute, an array. This class implements `\Countable`, `\IteratorAggregate`, and the most important for this question, `\ArrayAccess`.

But when using :

```
        usort($collectionData, function($a, $b) {
            return ($a->getPosition() > $b->getPosition());
        });
```

I get the following catchable exception :

> Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in
>   /home/alain/workspace/(...)n.php line 1057 (500 Internal Server Error)

I can trick using an intermediate variable :

```
        $data = $collectionData->getData();
        usort($data, function($a, $b) {
            return ($a->getPosition() > $b->getPosition());
        });
        $collectionData->setData($data);
```

But wanted to know if there is an SPL interface that can pass through the array parameter type expectation of `usort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. No interface will make your object be also an `array` and that's what you need to pass to `usort()`. However you can encapsulate this behaviour in your class by adding `usort()` method to your class.

```
class CollectionEntity implements Countable, IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess {

  private $data = array();

  /* other methods omitted for simplicity */

  public function usort(Closure $callback) {
    usort($this->data,$callback);
  }


}
```

Comment: this is the only way to do it afaik as well

Comment: Of course your way is better than mine. That's so unfortunate to be unable to overload the `array` type where we have so many native array manipulation functions in PHP.

Comment: BTW: this looks like a great use case for `trait`s

Answer (score 2):

I really think the only class you should extend is  `ArrayIterator` because it already implements

> ArrayIterator implements Iterator , Traversable , ArrayAccess , SeekableIterator , Countable , Serializable

Also also it supports

```
 public void uasort ( string $cmp_function )
 public void uksort ( string $cmp_function )
```

[And so many other methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php)

So you class is as simple as

```
class CollectionEntity extends ArrayIterator {
}
```

Then

```
$collectionData->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a->getPosition() > $b->getPosition());
});
```

Comment: Yes you can implement `offsetSet` .... as i said  `ArrayIterator` also implements `ArrayAccess`

Comment: yep, I seen that just after writting my comment (that's why I removed it).

Answer (score -2):

There is no such interface, array functions can *only* work on native arrays. However, you can convert Traversables such as `IteratorAggregate` to arrays with [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator-to-array)

By the way, here is an explanation why especially `ArrayAccess` does not help: [PHP: how can I sort and filter an "array", that is an Object, implementing ArrayAccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919172/php-how-can-i-sort-and-filter-an-array-that-is-an-object-implementing-array/14919719#14919719)